# How to speed up runtime of code that searches for data between several arrays within a 'moving' sphere

Tags: matlab

I am trying to average my CFD data (which is in the form of a scalar N x M x P array; N corresponds to Y, M to x, and P to z) over a subset of time steps. I've tried to simplify the description of my desired averaging process below.

1. Rotate the grid at each time step by a specified angle (*this is because the flow has a coherent structure that rotates and changes shape/size at each time step and I want to overlap them and find a time averaged form of the structure that takes into account the change of shape/size over time*)
2. Drawing a sphere centered on the original unrotated grid
3. Identifying the grid points from all the rotated grids that lie within the sphere
4. Identify the indices of the grid points in each rotated grid
5. Use the indices to find the scalar data at the rotated grid points within the sphere
6. Take an average of the values within the sphere
7. Put that new averaged value at the location on the unrotated grid

I have a code that seems to do what I want correctly, but it takes far too long to finish the calculations. I would like to make it run faster, and I am open to changing the code if necessary. Below is version of my code that works with a smaller version of the data.

```
x = -5:5;       % x - position data
y = -2:.5:5;    % y - position data
z = -5:5;       % z - position data
% my grid is much bigger actually

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);    % mesh for plotting data

dX = diff(x)';   dX(end+1) = dX(end);    % x grid intervals
dY = diff(y)';   dY(end+1) = dY(end);    % y grid intervals
dZ = diff(z)';   dZ(end+1) = dZ(end);    % z grid intervals

TestPoints = combvec(x,y,z)';    % you need the Matlab Neural Network Toolbox to run this
dXYZ = combvec(dX',dY',dZ')';

% TestPoints is the unrotated grid

M = length(x);   % size of grid x - direction
N = length(y);   % size of grid y - direction
P = length(z);   % size of grid z - direction

D = randi([-10,10],N,M,P,3);    % placeholder for data for 3 time steps (I have more than 3, this is a subset)
D2{3,M*N*P} = [];
PosAll{3,2} = [];

[xSph,ySph,zSph] = sphere(50);

c = 0.01;   % 1 cm
nu = 8e-6;  % 8 cSt
s = 3*c;    % span for Aspect Ratio 3
r_g = s/sqrt(3);
U_g = 110*nu/c; % velocity for Reynolds number 110
Omega = U_g/r_g;    % angular velocity
T = (2*pi)/Omega;   % period
dt = 40*T/1920;     % time interval
DeltaRotAngle = ((2*pi)/T)*dt;  % angle interval

timesteps = 121:123;   % time steps 121, 122, and 123
for ti=timesteps
    tj = find(ti==timesteps);
    Theta = ti*DeltaRotAngle;
    Rotate = [cos(Theta),0,sin(Theta);...
        0,1,0;...
        -sin(Theta),0,cos(Theta)];
    PosAll{tj,1} = (Rotate*TestPoints')';
end

for i=1:M*N*P
    aa = TestPoints(i,1);
    bb = TestPoints(i,2);
    cc = TestPoints(i,3);
    rs = 0.8*sqrt(dXYZ(i,1)^2 + dXYZ(i,2)^2 + dXYZ(i,3)^2);

    handles.H = figure;
    hs = surf(xSph*rs+aa,ySph*rs+bb,zSph*rs+cc);
    [Fs,Vs,~] = surf2patch(hs,'triangle');
    close(handles.H)

    for ti=timesteps
        tj = find(timesteps==ti);
        f = inpolyhedron(Fs,Vs,PosAll{tj,1},'FlipNormals',false);

        TestPointsR_ti = PosAll{tj,1};
        PointsInSphere = TestPointsR_ti(f,:);

        p1 = [aa,bb,cc];
        p2 = [PointsInSphere(:,1),...
            PointsInSphere(:,2),...
            PointsInSphere(:,3)];

        w = 1./sqrt(sum(...
            (p2-repmat(p1,size(PointsInSphere,1),1))...
            .^2,2));

        D_ti = reshape(D(:,:,:,tj),M*N*P,1);
        D2{tj,i} = [D_ti(f),w];
    end
end

D3{M*N*P,1} = [];
for i=1:M*N*P
    D3{i} = vertcat(D2{:,i});
end

D4 = zeros(M*N*P,1);
for i=1:M*N*P
    D4(i) = sum(D3{i}(:,1).*D3{i}(:,2))/...
                sum(D3{i}(:,2));
end
D_ta = reshape(D4,N,M,P);
```

I expect to get an N x M x P array where each index is the weighted average of all the points covering all of the time steps at that specific position in the unrotated grid. As you can see this is exactly what I get. The major problem however is the length of time it takes to do so when I use the larger set of my 'real' data. The code above takes only a couple minutes to run, but when M = 120, N = 24, and P = 120, and the number of time steps is 24 this can take much longer. Based on my estimates it would take approximately 25+ days to finish the entire calculation.

Comment: For anyone looking at this you need this https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I can help you with the math. What you are trying to do here is find things inside a sphere. You have a well-defined sphere so this makes things easy. Just find the distance of all points from the center point. No need to plot or use inpolyhedron. Note line 66 where I modify the points by the center point of the sphere, compute the distance of these points, and compare to the radius of the sphere.

```
% x = -5:2:5;       % x - position data
x = linspace(-5,5,120);
% y = -2:5;    % y - position data
y = linspace(-2,5,24);
% z = -5:2:5;       % z - position data
z = linspace(-5,5,120);
% my grid is much bigger actually

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);    % mesh for plotting data

dX = diff(x)';   dX(end+1) = dX(end);    % x grid intervals
dY = diff(y)';   dY(end+1) = dY(end);    % y grid intervals
dZ = diff(z)';   dZ(end+1) = dZ(end);    % z grid intervals

TestPoints = combvec(x,y,z)';    % you need the Matlab Neural Network Toolbox to run this
dXYZ = combvec(dX',dY',dZ')';

% TestPoints is the unrotated grid

M = length(x);   % size of grid x - direction
N = length(y);   % size of grid y - direction
P = length(z);   % size of grid z - direction

D = randi([-10,10],N,M,P,3);    % placeholder for data for 3 time steps (I have more than 3, this is a subset)
D2{3,M*N*P} = [];
PosAll{3,2} = [];

[xSph,ySph,zSph] = sphere(50);

c = 0.01;   % 1 cm
nu = 8e-6;  % 8 cSt
s = 3*c;    % span for Aspect Ratio 3
r_g = s/sqrt(3);
U_g = 110*nu/c; % velocity for Reynolds number 110
Omega = U_g/r_g;    % angular velocity
T = (2*pi)/Omega;   % period
dt = 40*T/1920;     % time interval
DeltaRotAngle = ((2*pi)/T)*dt;  % angle interval

timesteps = 121:123;   % time steps 121, 122, and 123
for ti=timesteps
    tj = find(ti==timesteps);
    Theta = ti*DeltaRotAngle;
    Rotate = [cos(Theta),0,sin(Theta);...
        0,1,0;...
        -sin(Theta),0,cos(Theta)];
    PosAll{tj,1} = (Rotate*TestPoints')';
end
tic
for i=1:M*N*P

    aa = TestPoints(i,1);
    bb = TestPoints(i,2);
    cc = TestPoints(i,3);
    rs = 0.8*sqrt(dXYZ(i,1)^2 + dXYZ(i,2)^2 + dXYZ(i,3)^2);

%     handles.H = figure;
%     hs = surf(xSph*rs+aa,ySph*rs+bb,zSph*rs+cc);
%     [Fs,Vs,~] = surf2patch(hs,'triangle');
%     close(handles.H)

    for ti=timesteps
        tj = find(timesteps==ti);

%         f = inpolyhedron(Fs,Vs,PosAll{tj,1},'FlipNormals',false);
        f = sqrt(sum((PosAll{tj,1}-[aa,bb,cc]).^2,2))<rs;
        TestPointsR_ti = PosAll{tj,1};
        PointsInSphere = TestPointsR_ti(f,:);

        p1 = [aa,bb,cc];
        p2 = [PointsInSphere(:,1),...
            PointsInSphere(:,2),...
            PointsInSphere(:,3)];

        w = 1./sqrt(sum(...
            (p2-repmat(p1,size(PointsInSphere,1),1))...
            .^2,2));

        D_ti = reshape(D(:,:,:,tj),M*N*P,1);
        D2{tj,i} = [D_ti(f),w];
    end
    if ~mod(i,10)
        toc
    end
end

D3{M*N*P,1} = [];
for i=1:M*N*P
    D3{i} = vertcat(D2{:,i});
end

D4 = zeros(M*N*P,1);
for i=1:M*N*P
    D4(i) = sum(D3{i}(:,1).*D3{i}(:,2))/...
                sum(D3{i}(:,2));
end
D_ta = reshape(D4,N,M,P);
```

In terms of runtime, on my computer, the old code takes 57 hours to run. The new code takes 2 hours. At this point, the main calculation is the distance so I doubt you'll get much better.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to in the meantime split the entire search volume into several sub volumes, and use `vertcat` on the position and flow data to make a single array covering all time time steps so that I could vectorize the process. One sub-volume took 15 min to run so combining your change and my vectorization should make the runtime even faster.

Comment: Note that if you implement on a GPU you can run even faster. I was able to achieve a 2x speedup with mine. Kinda weird I'm not getting more. Usually get 10-15x with this size of problem.

Comment: What do you mean GPU? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Graphics processing unit, they're much faster than your CPU for single precision operations. Try typing `gpuDevice` into your command line

Comment: That gives me an error, that may be because this is on a work computer at my university.

Comment: It means you don't have a GPU, don't worry about it then.

Comment: Officially it takes 42 seconds to complete the calculations for one sub-volume!